# Algorithmic Image Processing+Editing - Matlab vs Gimp

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have some image processing and editing tasks like resizing images based on various algorithmic outputs such as largest cyclic edges/contour in the image, filtering out certain colors, as well as remove certain backgrounds similar to a green screen. I am more inclined towards using MATLAB for this. Are there any advantages over MATLAB if I use GIMP?
Programming/Scripting language or API integration is not a factor.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For algorithmic image manipulation there is very little that can equal [OpenCV3](http://opencv.org/).

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Write **your** code in C++ *for speed* or python *for rapid development*
- Huge number of image manipulations built in & optimised

While in the python field you should also look at image manipulations using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), [Sci-Kit Image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html) & [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) all of which have some major strengths.

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed out on that.